# Google maps code show current location and creat new marker when touched in Php:- Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I´m trying to make my code to show a marker in the currect location and also to set a new marker when I touch or cick the screen,this is what i have so far, most of the code i have founded it on this web and craked my head to make work since i am not a programmer.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Google Maps</title>

<style>

    #map_canvas{
        height:800px;
        width:800px;
    }   
    </style>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script>        
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
      var marker, map;

      function initialize() {

        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 14,
          center: {lat: 20.58333333, lng: -100.41700278},
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }  

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), 
            mapOptions);    
var lavaditozone = [
    {lat: 20.59093056, lng: -100.433975},
    {lat: 20.57652778, lng: -100.433975},
    {lat: 20.57652778, lng: -100.40218611},
    {lat: 20.58610278, lng: -100.4120722},
    {lat: 20.59093056, lng: -100.433975}
  ];

  var arealavadito = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: lavaditozone ,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 10
  });
  arealavadito.setMap(map);

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
            addMarker(event.latLng);
        });     
      }

      function addMarker(latLng){       
        //clear the previous marker and circle.
        if(marker != null){
            marker.setMap(null);
        }    
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            draggable:false
        });           

var position =latLng ;
    window.document.title = position;       
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which technology you are using for googlemap Android,c#,php ...what ??

Comment: this is look like script and html so

Comment: Exactly this is html,currently i´m testng it on firefox

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i dont know hot to make it show a marker with the current location

Answer (score 0):

You have to give current position object to initialize function in order to get current position

```
  function initialize(curr_position) {
      var map_center = new google.maps.LatLng(curr_position.coords.latitude, curr_position.coords.longitude);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 14,
      center: map_center,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }  

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), 
        mapOptions);    
    var lavaditozone = [
        {lat: 20.59093056, lng: -100.433975},
        {lat: 20.57652778, lng: -100.433975},
        {lat: 20.57652778, lng: -100.40218611},
        {lat: 20.58610278, lng: -100.4120722},
        {lat: 20.59093056, lng: -100.433975}
    ];

   var arealavadito = new google.maps.Polyline({
       path: lavaditozone ,
       strokeColor: '#FF0000',
       strokeOpacity: 1,
       strokeWeight: 10
    });
    arealavadito.setMap(map);

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event){
        addMarker(event.latLng);
    });    
  }
```